# Loop instead of boucle (programming)

Tags: anglais, usage, informatique

En informatique/programmation/algorithmique, les mots boucle et loop, peuvent-ils être employés interchangeablement ?

Par exemple *while loop* au lieu de « boucle tant que », *for loop* au lieu de « boucle for » etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On ne traduit en général pas les noms d'instructions ou de mots clés du langage, donc ***while*** et ***for*** restent le plus souvent inchangés, sauf si le langage est en français bien sûr (rarissime<sup>1</sup>), où éventuellement si on décrit le concept algorithmique sans s'appuyer sur un langage précis (Université de Lille: la [**boucle tant que**](https://www.fil.univ-lille1.fr/%7Ewegrzyno/portail/InitProg/Doc/CTD/ctdTantQue.pdf), la [**boucle pour**](https://www.fil.univ-lille1.fr/%7Ewegrzyno/portail/InitProg/Doc/CTD/ctdBclePour.pdf)).

En revanche, ***loop*** peut très bien se traduire par **boucle** et c'est même l'usage le plus courant. On ne dit pas vraiment « la *loop* ». On parlera donc le plus souvent d'une **[boucle while](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boucle_while)** ou d'une **[boucle for](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boucle_for)**.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>En voici quand même un exemple, en langage [**linotte**](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linotte_(langage)) :</sub>

[image]

[Source](http://langagelinotte.free.fr/linotte/10minutes/10minutes20.html)

Comment: Thanks! The link seems to not work.

Comment: Which one? All of the five links of my reply work with me.

Comment: Sorry! This one: En voici quand même un exemple, en langage linotte : Page not found
/wik
We could not find the above page on our servers.
Did you mean: /wiki/wik
Alternatively, you can visit the Main Page or read more information about this type of error.

Comment: Ah, I overlook that one when I reviewed my reply. Fixed now.

Comment: Kein Problem :-)!

Answer (score 2):

Oui.

Il est très courant de dire "*Ici on utilise une boucle for parce que [...]*" ou "*Ceci est une boucle tant que [...]*", notamment lors de l'apprentissage de ces langages.

Tout d'abord, "boucle" est la traduction littérale de "loop".

Ensuite, lorsque l'on explique ces boucles, on utilise des phrases entièrement en français, simplifiant ainsi la compréhension de concept informatique grâce à des mots utilisés

Dire les mots anglais dans une phrase française est également valide car on parle de quelque chose de spécifique.